# Draw lines in a barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

Im trying to draw lines in a boxplot.If I want to change the length of the line (more than 1 difference) I get an error, why is this? The y position will be the same. How can I fix it? Thanks!

```
x <- barplot(c(1,2,3,5,6))
y <- 4.5
offset <- 0.1
lines(x[1:2],c(y,y))
lines(x[c(1,1)],c(y,y-offset))
lines(x[c(2,2)],c(y,y-offset))
```

[image]

```
x <- barplot(c(1,2,3,5,6))
y <- 4.5
offset <- 0.1
lines(x[1:3],c(y,y))
```

> Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

```
lines(x[c(1,1)],c(y,y-offset))
lines(x[c(3,3)],c(y,y-offset))
```

Comment: The first two arguments of the `lines` function must be the same length. You may have wanted: `lines(x[c(1,3)],c(y,y))`. Read the help page of `lines` under __Details__.

Comment: @Edward Hi!  Then I get this error... lines(x[1,3],c(y,y))
Error in x[1, 3] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: Check my answer carefully. ;)  Maybe copy and paste it instead of typing it manually.

Comment: @Edward, I missed c(1,3). Now it works, thanks a lot!